# NullPointerException in Hibernate Query: "org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.SqlAstProcessingState.getSqlExpressionResolver()" is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm experiencing a `NullPointerException` while executing a Hibernate query in a Spring Boot application. The issue seems to occur deep within the Hibernate framework, as indicated by the stack trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.SqlAstProcessingState.getSqlExpressionResolver()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.getCurrentProcessingState()" is null

This exception is thrown when invoking a custom repository method named `_loadAggregatedOrganizations`. The method is designed to process a list of entities based on another list of entities. The entities are part of a complex inheritance structure and have various relationships.

I suspect the issue might be related to how Hibernate processes the query with these entities, particularly with regards to their relationships or inheritance mapping.

- **Method in Repository:**

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Organization.loadAggregatedData", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM Organization o where o in :organizations")
List<Organization> _loadAggregatedOrganizations(@Param("organizations") List<? extends Contact> organizations);
```

I am using Hibernate version [6.2.13.Final], Spring Boot version [3.1.4], Spring Data JPA Version [3.0.9], Spring Framework Version [6.0.13]. I've checked the configuration and mappings but couldn't find any obvious misconfigurations. This issue arises specifically with a Jakarta packages with Java 17, when I downgrade to (traditional javax.* packages) with lower dependency versions which supports javax.* it works fine.

Can someone help me understand the root cause of this NullPointerException and how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.SqlAstProcessingState.getSqlExpressionResolver()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.getCurrentProcessingState()" is null
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.getSqlExpressionResolver(BaseSqmToSqlAstConverter.java:718)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.lambda$generateJoinPredicate$3(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1368)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.BasicValuedModelPart.forEachSelectable(BasicValuedModelPart.java:62)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.generateJoinPredicate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1365)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.generateTableReferenceJoin(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1342)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createTableReferenceJoin(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1312)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.lambda$createTableGroupInternal$6(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:2173)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.StandardTableGroup.potentiallyCreateTableReference(StandardTableGroup.java:180)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.StandardTableGroup.getTableReference(StandardTableGroup.java:160)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.ColumnReferenceQualifier.resolveTableReference(ColumnReferenceQualifier.java:37)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.ColumnReferenceQualifier.resolveTableReference(ColumnReferenceQualifier.java:20)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getAliasInWhere(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3175)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.applyWhereRestrictions(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3164)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.lambda$createTableGroupJoin$2(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:1975)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.LazyTableGroup.getTableGroup(LazyTableGroup.java:96)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.DelegatingTableGroup.getPrimaryTableReference(DelegatingTableGroup.java:166)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.StandardTableGroup.getTableReference(StandardTableGroup.java:170)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.CaseStatementDiscriminatorMappingImpl$CaseStatementDiscriminatorExpression.lambda$renderToSql$0(CaseStatementDiscriminatorMappingImpl.java:246)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.CaseStatementDiscriminatorMappingImpl$CaseStatementDiscriminatorExpression.renderToSql(CaseStatementDiscriminatorMappingImpl.java:244)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSelfRenderingExpression(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:6708)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.expression.SelfRenderingExpression.accept(SelfRenderingExpression.java:20)
at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLSqlAstTranslator.renderExpressionAsClauseItem(PostgreSQLSqlAstTranslator.java:64)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.renderSelectExpression(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:5070)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSqlSelectExpression(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:5065)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSqlSelection(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:5047)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSqlSelections(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:4712)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSelectClause(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:4613)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3081)
at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(PostgreSQLSqlAstTranslator.java:186)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.select.QuerySpec.accept(QuerySpec.java:119)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSelectStatement(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:988)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translateSelect(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:851)
at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:801)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:372)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:268)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:244)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518)
at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:127)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:72)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy193._loadAggregatedOrganizations(Unknown Source)
at org.gaurav.pr.repository.OrganizationRepository.loadAggregatedOrganizations(OrganizationRepository.java:130)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:732)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:78)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy193.loadAggregatedOrganizations(Unknown Source)
at org.gaurav.pr.service.ContactServiceImpl.loadAggregatedContacts(ContactServiceImpl.java:532)
at org.gaurav.pr.service.ContactServiceImpl.loadAggregatedContacts(ContactServiceImpl.java:465)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy201.loadAggregatedContacts(Unknown Source)
at org.gaurav.pr.service.MatterService.loadAggregatedMatterForDetailView(MatterService.java:2071)
at org.gaurav.pr.service.MatterService.findOneByIdAccount(MatterService.java:638)
at org.gaurav.pr.service.MatterService.findOneByIdAccount(MatterService.java:629)
at org.gaurav.pr.service.MatterService.getWithCache(MatterService.java:614)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:54)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:366)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:420)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at org.gaurav.pr.service.MatterService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getWithCache(<generated>)
at org.gaurav.pr.web.api.v2.MattersApi.getWithCache(MattersApi.java:1637)
at org.gaurav.pr.web.api.v2.MattersApi.getWithCache(MattersApi.java:1632)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
at org.gaurav.pr.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:83)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor152.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:637)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:71)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at org.gaurav.pr.web.api.v2.MattersApi$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getWithCache(<generated>)
at org.gaurav.pr.web.api.v2.MattersApi.get(MattersApi.java:1522)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
at org.gaurav.pr.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:83)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor152.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:637)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:71)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:58)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:173)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:199)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at org.gaurav.pr.web.api.v2.MattersApi$$SpringCGLIB$$0.get(<generated>)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.gaurav.pr.security.HTTPSecurityHeadersFilter.doFilter(HTTPSecurityHeadersFilter.java:38)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.gaurav.pr.security.creditcardcheck.CreditCardCheckFilter.doFilter(CreditCardCheckFilter.java:60)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.gaurav.pr.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.gaurav.pr.security.HttpRequestDecompressionFilter.doFilter(HttpRequestDecompressionFilter.java:36)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.gaurav.pr.security.webdav.WebDavFilter.doFilter(WebDavFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.gaurav.pr.security.jwt.KeycloakJWTFilter.doFilter(KeycloakJWTFilter.java:37)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.gaurav.pr.security.RequestDurationFilter.doFilter(RequestDurationFilter.java:39)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
```

Comment: 99% of the time the cause is in your code, or your Spring bean wiring configuration.  Please [edit] your post and include the _complete_ stack trace.  There's nowhere near enough information here for your post to be on-topic.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have also added the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `in :organizations` use `in (:organizations)`.

Also remove `@Param("organizations")` and `value =`  yagni

And use an Iterable, not an List cause of immutability.

Hey, is a organization an contact? May you mix different entities? What is this method about at all? There are no aggregations from my pov.